# I got a server and several domains. Now what?

Tags: ftp, domain, nameserver

I am very new to servers and domains, etc, so please forgive the following ignorance:

I have hosting through ServInt as well as several domains. A few domains are through GoDaddy and some others through 1&1. One of my GoDaddy domains is set up already (don't ask me how - someone did it for me). I need to forward the other 2 GoDaddy domains to the one that is set up or at least link them all to the same content. I currently upload files to this site using the Transmit FTP client. I also have access to this site's CPanel. What is the process for directing the other 2 domains to the working one?

Also, I have 2 domains with 1&1 that I want to link together in the same way, but neither one is set up with nameservers/CPanel/FTP. I'm not sure how to connect these domain to ServInt hosting (I know it involves nameservers/DNS) but it's over my head. What is the process for creating CPanel and web access for a new domain and establishing FTP?

Thank you in advance

R. Hue

Answer (score 1):

You will need to tell your domain registrar to use specific 'authoritative' servers. You can either set up your own authoritative servers or use some existing services on the internet. You need to read up on how domain names work. In particular, look out for A-records and CNAME-records. These are the most useful in your case. Hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: To make it easy on myself, I want to tackle just one issue today. How can I take one of my 1&1 domains and connect it to my hosting? I just want to see something when I enter the domain...

Comment: You will typically need to use the hosting company's nameserver as the authoritative nameserver. This involves getting the config information from your hosting and entering those nameservers into your domain registry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start reading - a lot. Start with the documentation for the various bits and pieces that make up the system you're trying to cobble together. Also study DNS and learn what it's for and how to use it. Only when you understand these things should you be contemplating doing what you have already started to do.

Comment: I think it's definitely over my head, but I know a bit… I know DNS is a type of nameserver that turns a domain to something like a shortcut to the actual IP address of the website. Evidently, domains can have multiple nameservers. I do not understand how to create those nameservers or how to get them. And I don't know how to link the domain to an FTP client. Any tutorial or advice to get me over the hump?

Comment: Google is your friend. It will reveal far more than I could possibly enter into a reply. Start with searches such as "dns tutorial". Once you get the basics the searches will become more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point the domains to the web hosting companies DNS servers.

First, figure out what those nameservers are. They will usually be ns1.host.com and ns2.host.com. (where "host.com" is the hosting companies domain"

Then, log in to godaddy, and find the "my domains" section. You will see a list of your domains. Choose "edit" for the one you want to point to the host, and you will see a tab that says either "DNS" or "Name Servers". By default, the name will be "parked" with go daddy.

Choose the option that says "host my names elsewhere" (or something to that effect) and you'll be taken to a page that let's you enter the name of your nameservers. Enter "ns1.host.com" and "ns2.host.com" and save the changes. Be advised this could take up to 48 hours while the changes propagate throughout the Internet.

Once this is done, in Cpanel, you should (if your host has allowed it) see an option for domain aliases. Enter your domain names there, and they should now point to the same site.

If you're concerned about SEO, you may also want to setup an .htaccess file that 301 redirects the other two names to the first one.

Comment: If I already have 2 nameservers on ServInt (for the domain that is set up), how can I create some new ones for other domains? The cPanel seems to be specific to the one domain and I don't see a way to add domains in CPanel.

Comment: Is your intention to point several domains to a single site? I don't have a CPanel in front of me to see, but usually there is a section called "domains" with an option "Aliases". If it's missing from CPanel, perhaps your host doesn't allow it?

Comment: I have 2 sites that span 5 domains... I'm less concerned about redirects/aliases as I am just getting the 2nd site off the ground. And to connect that domain with the hosting, it wants to know 2 nameservers. Can I just put ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com or do they need to be set up in advance?

Comment: In the Godaddy tool, you would use the name-severs that your hosting company provides. Your basically telling GoDaddy which web hosting company you want your names to point at.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to do some reading.  Answering these very general questions here is like trying to teach someone to drive by telling them over the Internet.

Look for tutorial-style articles on DNS and web hosting in general.  Depending on the kind of hosting service you have, they may be willing to hold your hand.  Do a little reading then come back with your more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

The account at ServInt will come with two nameservers setup. First check at the registrar of this domain, if these nameservers are registered at all as nameservers. This is a special process to ensure that the root nameservers will know them.

Then the nameserver records at your registrar (GoDaddy, 1&1) need to point to your account's nameserver at ServInt. This must be handled at GoDaddy and 1&1. There should be a form to enter this information.

After this go into cPanel of the account where you want to add your domain. There should be two option to add a domain (point it at a directory in your account) or to stack it on the account's domain. cPanel will create the DNS setup and configure Apache accordingly.

The ServInt NOC is very helpfull and fast. If you encouter problems just open a ticket.